# Chinese is not displayed in ActivePDF

Tags: asp.net, .net, pdf, pdf-generation

I am going to use ActivePDF to generate Chinese reports via Asp.net application.

Example

```
Dim oTK As APToolkitNET.Toolkit = New APToolkitNET.Toolkit()
oTK.NewPage()
oTK.SetFont("Helvetica|encoding=UniGB-UCS2-H", 24)
oTK.PrintText(72.0, 720.0, "每日活动报表")
```

PDF file is generated, but it always displays "kˇeåm;R¤b¥hE" instead of "每日活动报表".

please let me know what should I do?

meta tag is already defined to set (content="text/html; charset=utf-8") in aspx page level.

Comment: Helvetica is one of the Standard 14 Fonts which PDF viewers have to support out of the box but only with a limited character set which essentially is some Latin charset variant. Have you tried a different font yet? (This comment assumes that ActivePDF does not do any remappings of fonts here.)

Comment: Yer,Tried for all font options.. Nothing is succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

The only encodings supported by the built-in fonts are WinAnsiEncoding, MacRomanEncoding, MacExpertEncoding and Custom (using one of the previous 3 as a base encoding).

You need a font where the glyphs are defined for that encoding. The built in Helvetica font does not have the glyphs defined for "每日活动报表".  Try using Arial Unicode MS instead.